# Why does scipy.signal.cont2discrete return dt?

Tags: python, scipy

The function `signal.cont2discrete` from the scipy module transforms a system defined in continuous time to its discrete version, using the time interval `dt`, which is enter as a parameter.
The thing is, the time interval is included among the things that the function returns. **What's the sense in that?** The documentation of the function says nothing about that, so I read the code of the function (using inspect.getsource), thinking that maybe the returned dt could be different from the entered dt.. But it can't. The function just take dt as a parameter and returns the exact same dt (amongst other useful returned things, of course). Anybody knows why that could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The convention used for discrete time systems in `scipy.signal` is to represent a system using one of the following forms:

```
(num, den, dt)
(zeros, poles, gain, dt)
(A, B, C, D, dt)
```

(See, for example, the parameters accepted by [`dlsim`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.dlsim.html), [`dstep`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.dstep.html), etc.)
The return value of [`cont2discrete`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.cont2discrete.html) follows that convention.